# usage of あって to determine a cause

Tags: grammar

I have been struggling to find information on how ”あって” works in the following sentence :

家や会社では静かですが、いざかやに行くとお酒の力**もあって**とてもにぎやかになります。

I think in this case ”あって” means "because of", but how does it work exactly ?

Does it go together with the も？ Does it relate to "酒の力” or to the whole ”行くとお酒の力” proposition ?

Is it specific to ある or is this a て-form usage that works with other verbs ?

I hope my question make sense. Thanks in advance for your help !

W

Answer (score 3):

This ある is just the usual verb denoting the existence of something i.e. "there is".
お酒の力もある means "there is also the effect of alcohol".

You probably know that the te-form is used to join clauses with the meaning of "and", but it can also imply a degree of causality in the same way that the "and" in "it's cold and I'm miserable" also provides a causal connection, so お酒の力もあってとてもにぎやかになります would be "there is the effect of alcohol and I get lively".

There is still another way to think of the te-form. You are no doubt familiar with the particle で with the meaning of "by means of" e.g. お箸で食べた ("I ate with (by means of) chopsticks"). You can also use the te-form to adverbially modify the following clause. e.g. お箸を使って食べた ("I ate using (by means of) chopsticks". So another way to think of お酒の力もあってとてもにぎやかになります is "I get lively due to (by means of there existing) the effect of alcohol".

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for yout answer. It is true I didn't see this ”あって” as a way to join clauses - since then I would have expected the 行く before to also be in its te form, right ? 


居酒屋に行ってお酒の力もあってとても賑やかになります


Indeed I didn't know about the te- forme being used to adverbially modifiy a clause - which completely makes sense here. 

thanks again !

Comment: @Wignam You should not expect 行く to be in te-form. That と in いざかやに行くと is a conditional particle meaning 'if/when'. It attaches to the dictionary form of a verb. Removing it and changing to the te-form would break the sentence. I don't know how you are translating the full sentence but your comment worries me a little. Just for clarity the full translation is something like "I'm quiet at home and work but **when** I go to the izakaya I get lively due to the effect of alcohol".

Comment: aaaaaah I see ! thanks again. You saw it right, I was understanding this と as an "and" and not conditionnal and thought the sentence was like "when i go to the izakaya AND drink alcoohol, i get lively" - your explanation makes so much more sense. Thanks again ! W